# Crashlytics download file

Tags: ios, configuration, settings, crashlytics

I Wonder, how crashlytics able to make all user to download their app is iOS without being on the app store. It's just a file downloaded in the mobile settings and add the 'beta' application after then. How this exactly works ?.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Over the Air Distribution". In general terms you can distribute ipa file using any web server in case you sign it in a right way. Apple developed this method for Enterprise distribution, but it works for Ad-Hoc builds too.
Here is [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html)